# Binding shared flyout to 2 controls in Listview's DataTemplate in UWP Windows 10

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, dependency-properties, windows-10-universal

I've got a shared `Flyout` defined in my `<Page.Resources>` as follows:

```
<Flyout x:Name="InfoFlyout" Opened="{Binding IsOpen,
        ElementName=MyListView, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <Grid>
        <Button Foreground="White" Margin="5">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Help"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Flyout>
```

But I get `An object reference not set` error when compiling, so I used the code from this article ([Using Windows 8.1 Flyout control with MVVM](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/07/30/using-windows-8-1-flyout-xaml-control-with-mvvm/)) instead.

This seems to circumvent the problem I was having with the above code. Now my shared `Flyout` code looks like this:

```
<Flyout x:Name="InfoFlyout"
        helpers:FlyoutHelpers.Parent="{Binding ElementName=MyListView}"
        helpers:FlyoutHelpers.IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <Grid>
    <Button Foreground="White" Margin="5">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Help"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
    </Grid>
</Flyout>
```

My `ListView` control (i.e. x:Name="MyListView") is binded to the page's `ViewModel` i.e. MainPageViewModel. The IsOpen property is defined in the MainViewModel.

Now in my `ListView` `DataTemplate`, I want my `Flyout` to open when I press and hold the `ListViewItem` or when pressing a button within the `ListViewItem`:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource InfoFlyout}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source={Binding MyImage} />
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Width="30" Height="30"
                    Flyout="{StaticResource InfoFlyout}"
                    content="i">
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Holding">
                <actions:OpenFlyoutAction />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

As you can see, I've got the `Flyout` "attached" to the `Grid` via:

```
FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource InfoFlyout}"
```

and I've got the same `Flyout` attached to the button within the `ListViewItem` itself via:

```
Flyout="{StaticResource InfoFlyout}"
```

I've put breakpoints on both my setter and getter for the IsOpen property and when page gets loaded, it does go into the getter but whenever I open or close my `Flyout` either via `Holding` or by pressing the 'i' button, it doesn't trigger the method below and therefore it doesn't change the IsOpen property.

```
private static void OnIsOpenPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,
DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) as defined in the FlyoutHelper class.
```

The reason I've set my `ElementName` to MyListView is that I want all my `ListViewItem` to be binded to the one property i.e. IsOpen as I need to detect whenever a flyout menu is opened irrelevant of which `ListViewItem` it belongs to.

How can I achieve or resolve this?

**UPDATE - 1**

The problem of accessing the shared menu has been resolved by using the following:

```
<Flyout x:Name="InfoFlyout"
        helpers:FlyoutHelpers.Parent="{Binding ElementName=MyListView}"
        helpers:FlyoutHelpers.IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

and setting the button to

```
<Button Width="30" Height="30"
Command="{Binding InformationCommand}"
CommandParameter="{Binding}"
Flyout="{StaticResource InfoFlyout}">
```

Which is fine and as @ElvisXia mentioned, you can comment out the code in the OnIsOpenPropertyChanged as the positioning is already determined by the button located inside my ListViewItem.

There is however one outstanding problem. A small one btw, but nice if it can be solved. The shared flyout which is attached to the grid itself in the DataTemplate i.e.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource InfoFlyout}">
```

It is being positioning based on the ListViewItem which technically is correct as I'm calling a different piece of code for that one i.e.

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Holding">
        <actions:OpenFlyoutAction />
    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

And the OpenFlyoutAction is defined as follows:

```
public class OpenFlyoutAction : DependencyObject, IAction
{
    public object Execute(object sender, object parameter)
    {
        FrameworkElement senderElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
        FlyoutBase flyoutBase = FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(senderElement);

        flyoutBase.ShowAt(senderElement);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Can I somehow stop using the `OpenFlyoutAction` and use the same code as provided in the article to open my `Flyout` wherever the user is holding his/her finger on the relevant `ListViewItem` rather than on top or below the actual `ListViewItem`?

I understand it's a little bit side track from the original issue which was to share a Flyout by to controls but may as well finish it as it is somehow relevant to the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: OnIsOpenPropertyChanged will be triggered when there is a change in IsOpen. Since you have bound custom IsOpen property you have to change it true when flyout is opening. Are you doing that?

Comment: No I'm not. I thought the idea was for it to change automatically when it was opening via the OnIsOpenPropertyChanged. I'll check the article again and revert back in a bit. Ideally, I would like to get the Opened built-in event to be binded and changed accordingly.

Comment: As of now OnIsOpenPropertyChanged is bounded to which property changed event? Is it to your custom IsOpen Property?If so When flyout is opened make your viewmodel property IsOpen to true. Since its two way binded it will trigger OnIsOpenPropertyChanged event

Comment: Just checked the article. Just check whether it is registering to Opening  and closed event of flyout in OnParentPropertyChanged event

Comment: Did you change the type of attachedProperty "Parent" in FlyoutHelpers.cs from Button to ListView? I made that mistake at first. After correcting that, everythings works fine.

Comment: It's not and that's the problem. That's the part I totally missed that it was registering the Opening and Closed when the parent was set but having said that, I still don't know why it's not registering the parent when you can see from the above that it is being set via the FlyoutHelpers.Parent="{Binding ElementName=CloudcardGrid}"

Comment: Please clarify, Did you change type  from Button to ListView?

Comment: Sorry laptop just died. Have to work another one and look at this later when I get it back up. Will revert asap. Sorry

Comment: @LovetoCode Back in action :). Anyway, well spotted, you were on the right track. I changed all the Button to Listview and code is now kicking in as expected but I still have a problem. As it is the listview rather than the listview item, it's now displaying my popup in the wrong place i.e. on top of listview. How can I bind it to the actual listview item? I've changed it to Control instead to see if I could see the actual object type being passed but it's not binded since I changed my FlyoutHelpers.Parent="{Binding}" as I'm not sure what to set it to. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes i have spotted that problem, I'll get back to you if i find solution

Comment: Same here. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Please check this code  whether fulfills your requirement.  private void Grid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)MyListView.ContainerFromItem((sender as Grid).DataContext);
            FlyoutHelpers.SetParent(FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(sender as Grid), item);
            FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(sender as Grid);
        }.  And i removed setting up parent in xaml

Comment: @LovetoCode - Can you actually post your comment as an answer as the more I think about it, it was your answer which resolve the problem. Positioning is nice to have it somehow resolved but the question was about using a shared Flyout between 2 controls which you resolved.

Comment: You mean last comment?

Comment: No I meant 'Did you change the type of attachedProperty "Parent" in FlyoutHelpers.cs from Button to ListView' as this was the original problem. I ended up changing it to control but this put me in the right direction to use a shared flyout based on provided code.

Comment: I guess its not poosible..

Comment: ok, fair enough. It's not the end of the world. Main thing is that now I've got a working shared Flyout. As mentioned, post what I mentioned above and I will accept this as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: You can use PopUp control instead. It has HorizontalOffset,VerticalOffset property. If you are interested to use i can share the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the type of Parent from Button to ListView. To open flyout in particular X,Y position is not possible in WP. You can choose PopUp control instead. Here is a link which i got [open the pop up in tapped position](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowshardware/ar-SA/e1d04c23-f964-4cd1-86ad-fb43c642c6e8/dynamic-position-of-flyout?forum=winappswithcsharp). You can use `VisualTreeHelper` to get PopUp control of tapped ListViewItem

Answer (score 0):

By [Using Windows 8.1 Flyout control with MVVM](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/07/30/using-windows-8-1-flyout-xaml-control-with-mvvm/) , the author use parent to control where the flyout shows up.
So the author have codes like below(FlyoutHelpers.cs):

```
private static void OnIsOpenPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var flyout = d as Flyout;
        var parent = (ListView)d.GetValue(ParentProperty);

        if (flyout != null && parent != null)
        {
            var newValue = (bool)e.NewValue;

            if (newValue)
              flyout.ShowAt(parent);
            else
              flyout.Hide();
        }
    }
```

He use `flyout.ShowAt(parent)` to let flyout show at parent element. But in your codes you have binded the flyout to the button using:

> ```
> <Button Width="30" Height="30"
>         Flyout="{StaticResource InfoFlyout}" content="i">
> </Button>
> ```

So it is not necessary to let it show at it's parent any more. To fix the problem, you can comment out the statements like below:

```
private static void OnIsOpenPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //var flyout = d as Flyout;
        //var parent = (ListView)d.GetValue(ParentProperty);

        //if (flyout != null && parent != null)
        //{
        //    var newValue = (bool)e.NewValue;

        //    if (newValue)
        //      flyout.ShowAt(parent);
        //    else
        //      flyout.Hide();
        //}
    }
```

Then you will see the flyout shows at the right place.

Comment: Sorry but I approved it too quickly! This takes care of the positioning when called from the button, but what about the Tap and Hold? This is triggering another piece of code which I'll add as an update to my question, but can I get rid of it and use the same method as above, if so, how? Thanks

Comment: what about the Tap and Hold? What is the problem?

Comment: @LovetoCode Check the updated answer. I'm explaining the problem there. Thanks